# Errors on Get-ADUser?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Sometimes :

```
(Get-AdUser -filter * -server contoso.com).count
```

Returns a good/proper output

Sometimes I get :

```
Local error
 
Category Info : 

NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException  

Fully Qualified Error ID :
    
ActiveDirectoryServer:8251,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Could please someone help me it would not work ?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like in those error cases you did not import the AD module `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`, or tried this on a machine not connected to an AD domain. Also, I would change the code line you have to `@(Get-AdUser -filter * -server contoso.com).count`. The `@()` forces the output to be an array, even if it has just one or no items at all. Then the `.Count` will not fail in these circumstances.

Comment: I surely did import the module if it worked yesterday on the same computer... I also tried your array advice but it seems to be the cmdlet itself which is causing the error

Comment: *" it worked yesterday on the same computer"* lol doesn't mean it will work today.  You say it doesnt work, but it also does? So only sometimes? It looks like enumeration is running into an issue. Run `$Error[0] | FL * -Force` to get more details.

Comment: If I request to DC1.contoso.com -> Works
If I request to DC2.contoso.com -> It doesn't work